# How to Insert Multiple Data to Database in One Column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i want to insert my array data to database in one column.

my column in database is `id(auto increment)` & `datas`.

here what i try, i get error.

i want my data like this

```
id(primary)(AI)(INT)           datas(varchar:255)
--------                       ----
       1                       3001182708
       2                       3001182713
       3                       3001183215
```

im try using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054725/9661872

```
$rand_post = ["3001182708", "3001182713", "3001183215", "3001183558", "3001183753"]; 

$prep = array();
foreach($rand_post as $k => $v ) {
    $prep[':'.$k] = $v;
    $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes (`datas`) VALUES (" . implode(', ',array_keys($prep)) . ")");
    $res = $sth->execute($prep);
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list
> does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value
> count at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\savelink\index.php:23 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\savelink\index.php(23): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\savelink\index.php on line 23

Comment: diferent problem i think

Comment: What's the type of your `datas` column in your table?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, you want to insert all this data to one row ? or you want to insert into diff rows.

Comment: @Pavel `varchar`

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid im edit my question, hope u can understant

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19680494/2943403

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/15069962/2943403

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48635174/2943403

Comment: When this gets properly closed, please add all links to the list (I don't have the privilege)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because each time you go through the loop you are increasing the size of the preps array, so the second time you are attempting to insert 2 values when only 1 column is specified in the query.

I think this is what you want to do. Basically it forms the entire preps array, then builds the statement from that and executes it.

```
$rand_post = ["3001182708", "3001182713", "3001183215", "3001183558", "3001183753"]; 

$prep = array();
foreach($rand_post as $k => $v ) {
    $prep[':'.$k] = $v;
}
print_r($prep);
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes (`datas`) VALUES (" . implode('), (',array_keys($prep)) . ")");
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

If you look at $sth and $prep at the end of this, you get

```
INSERT INTO tes (`datas`) VALUES (:0), (:1), (:2), (:3), (:4)
Array
(
    [:0] => 3001182708
    [:1] => 3001182713
    [:2] => 3001183215
    [:3] => 3001183558
    [:4] => 3001183753
)
```